# Console reporting "Deprecated" in 10.8.x

Tags: macos, console

Not that i know what it is but would like to fix it anyway!

My Console shows this...but to my knowledge my MBA 10.8.4 is working fine ?

> 6/23/13 11:35:31.952 AM System Preferences[3575]:
>
> *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later.
>
> Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:]
>   instead.

Honestly, I had to Google the word **deprecated** first to know what it means.

> Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature,
>   characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically
>   because of being superseded.

OK, so how do I fix that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a problem for you. The code is working correctly.

"Deprecate" is what is used in development to tell the developer who uses a library that the next version of a library will not include the method that they are using. This allows the library writers to remove code and let developers using the code prepare to change how they called the library in the next version.

Comment: Thank you, Who ever wrote that message could add "fordevelopersonly" so old ppl like me do not panic :)

Comment: Presumably they assumed (wrongly?) that anyone who reads the console knows what "deprecated" means.